# How can I set a Google Map Marker back to the default icon after changing it?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-utils

I am using the `android-maps-utils` library with a Google Map in an android app I'm working on, and I have several markers on the map. I change the icons for some markers when certain conditions are met using `setIcon()` with an `IconGenerator`.

I want to then change the icons *back* to the original red Google Maps standard icons when a different condition is met. I can track the condition and change them to a different custom icon, but don't know how to return them to the Google default short of finding an icon somewhere online and adding it into my project to add manually as I am with my personalized ones. Does anyone know how to retrieve the defaults?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

```
marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker());
```